# Dask client.map returns KeyError on dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, dask

I'm trying to create an updated example of random forest classification using python dask, as originally described [here](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/04/20/dask-distributed-part-5).

When I attempt to pass a training set to the Client.map function, it's throwing a KeyError and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong based on the error message.

Here's what I have:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from distributed import Client, progress, wait
c = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
c

columns = ['trip_distance', 'pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude', 
           'dropoff_longitude', 'dropoff_latitude', 'payment_type', 
           'fare_amount', 'mta_tax', 'tip_amount', 'tolls_amount']

import dask.dataframe as dd

dfs = dd.read_csv('s3://dask-data/nyc-taxi/2015/*.csv', 
                 parse_dates=['tpep_pickup_datetime', 'tpep_dropoff_datetime'],
                 storage_options={'anon': True})
dfs = c.persist(dfs)
progress(dfs)

def fit(df):
    est = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=4)
    est.fit(df[columns], df.passenger_count)
    return est

train, test = dfs.random_split([0.7, 0.3])

estimators = c.map(fit, train)
progress(estimators, complete=False)
```

which throws the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-9846f819ffca> in <module>()
      8 train, test = dfs.random_split([0.7, 0.3])
      9 
---> 10 estimators = c.map(fit, train)
     11 progress(estimators, complete=False)

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/client.py in map(self, func, *iterables, **kwargs)
   1243             raise ValueError("Only use allow_other_workers= if using workers=")
   1244 
-> 1245         iterables = list(zip(*zip(*iterables)))
   1246         if isinstance(key, list):
   1247             keys = key

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2284 
   2285             # error is raised from pandas
-> 2286             meta = self._meta[_extract_meta(key)]
   2287             dsk = dict(((name, i), (operator.getitem, (self._name, i), key))
   2288                        for i in range(self.npartitions))

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3841 
   3842             if not isna(item):
-> 3843                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3844             else:
   3845                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Based on the error output, the error appears to be getting triggered at the `estimators = c.map(fit, train)` statement, suggesting that `def fit(df):` probably needs to be modified so that the dask dataframe can be properly passed to `est.fit()`, but I am not sure how.

Comment: I'm not sure you can pass a dask dataframe to scikit-learn. Have you try to use `dask_ml` as explained in this [documentation](https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning.html)?